# Accordion MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to make an accordion in my page with [this tutorial](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-accordion/) but nothing works. This is my view:

```
@model  SGP.Models.Queries

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>

    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Assiduidade</h3>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {             
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Nome")
                        </th>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.query1)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                            </td>
                            ...
                        </tr>    
                    }
                </table>
            }
        </div>
        <h3>Avaliação</h3>
        <div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {                   
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Nome")
                        </th>
                        ...
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.query2)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            }
</div>
</div>
```

This is my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - SGP</title>
       ...
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/fullcalendar")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year 
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullcalendar")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

But when i run my application, there is no accordion. I added the jQuery-ui.css and the code in the BundleConfig like it says in the tutorial but nothing works. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please tell us if you have errors in console.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai No errors, only when i run it does not appear any accordion

Comment: You have some mistakes in your code:You've loaded twice some libraries in your `layout` page.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai i have just changed the layout to what it is displayed in the tutorial and still doesn't work

Comment: Please include jquery plugin in your view

Comment: Remove `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` from you view - you already have the correct scripts in the correct order in the layout. And `@Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")` is not correct (they are styles, not scripts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to include `jquery` plugin and `jquery-ui.css` in your view.

Another solution is to set `layout` in top of view.

```
@{
     Layout="~/your_layout_path";
}
```

Here is an example of working [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/xbzpno7k/)